# Function to Get POP UP Window in stand alone application using c sharp

Tags: c#

i am facing a problem with Getting a pop up message through pop up window in a stand alone application using c sharp.please help us ,thanks in advance.

I want to pop up a message to user to perform task at particular time .then i need to send the message to user through pop up window thats my requirement.
i am writing console application programs.

Regards,
M.Channabasappa

Comment: Please be more and more and more spesific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have console project - the best user message would, of course, console message. But If you still want to send pop up message to user just add reference to `System.Windows.Forms` assembly to your project and call message box:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello! Im console app");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,but i used the same the pop up window is not coming up.

Comment: @Channabasappa: cant get you, please rephrase

Comment: @Anton: i used System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please set the registry settings");   it is not poping up window with the message .

Comment: @Channabasappa: That's strange, very strange for me. I can't imagine any situation where it might be possible. Do you tried to debug your app, does execution reach message box line?

Comment: yes , i debugged even code reaches that point of pop up window.

Comment: @Channabasappa: I have no more ideas. Try to create brand new project and reproduce your error. Just create new console app and try out my advice. Its most like that all would be work. if so, you has some kind of problems in your current project, if no... I dont think this happens

Comment: @ But it worked in Single project still i dint get with stand alone project.

Answer (score 0):

In WinForms, you need `Form.ShowDialog()`. In WPF, it's `Window.ShowDialog()`.

To achieve a modal popup on a website is more tricky. Only IE really supports *modal* popups, and they don't "feel" nice to use. You can use bits of jQuery UI to get what looks like a popup but is in fact a div layered over the top of the whole page, inside the browser window.

HTH.

Comment: You're welcome, don't be afraid to upvote answers you find helpful (all of those that were of value to your question, you don't have to chose the "best" one). :)

Answer (score 0):

Anton's answer is correct, but in my case (Visual Studio 2010, Win7), I had to add `System.Windows.Forms` to my project as a reference to get it to work.

To do so, right click on your project in Solution Explorer > Add Reference > .NET tab > System.Windows.Forms > OK

Once I did this, I was able to add a MessageBox to a console application, which while it seems a bit counter intuitive was a good solution for this particular problem.